# Iterate of each table in accordion only once using jQuery

Tags: jquery, append, each, insertafter

I have an accordion with 5 sections. Inside each section is a table. If that table has more than 10 rows a View More link is appended. My problem is that the View More link is appended 5 time in the first table. 4 time in the second table. 3 time in the third table. And so on...

How do I append the View More link just once on every table where there are more than 10 (or 2) rows.

```
$(".accordion-group table tbody").each(function() {

    var row = $(this).find("tr");
    var colunm = $(this).find("tr:first td");

    row.last().addClass("last");

    var rowCount = row.length;
    var columnCount = colunm.length;

    if (rowCount > 10) {
        $("<tr><td colspan=" + columnCount + " class=\"view_more_accordian\" style=\"text-align:center;\">View more</td></tr>").insertAfter(".last");
    }
}); });
```

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Can you show your html as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is that in your insertAfter selctor you provide `tbody` and which will return all of them and insert after all of the available tbody's, instead just append it to the current tbody i.e `this`.

Change

```
$("<tfoot><tr><td colspan=" + columnCount + " class=\"view_more_accordian\" style=\"text-align:center;\">View more</td></tr></tfoot>")
  .insertAfter("tbody");
```

to

```
$("<tfoot><tr><td colspan=" + columnCount + " class=\"view_more_accordian\" style=\"text-align:center;\">View more</td></tr></tfoot>")
  .insertAfter(this);
```

Also you can avoid using the first `.each` (based on your shown code) instead you can just do

```
$(".accordion-group table tbody").each(function () {
...
});
```

Comment: That worked great. But now my boss wants a tr inserted into the tbody as   the last row. So THIS refers to the tbody. And trying to use jQuery append(".last") doesn't work. Any ideas. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MWA Sorry din't get can you put them in a fiddle?

Comment: @MWA I did not understand but probably you might have to do `.append($(".last"))`. However if my original answer worked do you mind accepting it and you can add a new question for your query.

Comment: @MWA Saw you had updated your question, without seeing your html i cant surely say but try. `$("<tr><td colspan=" + columnCount + " class=\"view_more_accordian\" style=\"text-align:center;\">View more</td></tr>").insertAfter(row.last());` You dont have to add the class `.last`